# Detecting new emoji in text

Tags: python, regex, emoji

Until now I was using the following code in order to detect emojis in text

```
emoji_regexp = u'[\U00002600-\U000026FF]|[\U00002700-\U000027BF]|[\U0001f300-\U0001f5fF]|[\U0001f600-\U0001f64F]|' \
               u'[\U0001f680-\U0001f6FF]'
re.findall(emoji_regexp, text, re.UNICODE)
```

But currently there are some cases where it doesn't detect new emojis (check out new emojis in [this table](http://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts-beta/full-emoji-list.html#1f912)), such as this emoji . I know that there were new emojis in the latest iOS update so maybe it's connected somehow.

I believe that I should modify 'emoji_regexp' but not quite sure what to add there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find out if Character in String is emoji?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757193/find-out-if-character-in-string-is-emoji)

Comment: Nope, firstly I'm asking about Python, secondly the suggested solution does not deal with new emojis.

Comment: So, what is the problem? Just add those new symbols/sequences to your regex. Actually, it has nothing to do with NLP, it seems to be a pure regex issue.

Comment: This is basically my question, I'm looking for a new range to add to the regex, not a specific symbol. Any suggestions?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find an off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm not looking for an off-site resource or something like that, just asking if any one here can help me with figuring out how should I change the regex values that I'm using in order to detect these new emojis.

Comment: Since these days Unicode is constantly being expanded to support new emoji, this is something you'll have to continuously keep up to date with. Perhaps a different approach to dealing with whatever problem you're trying to solve here would be better, one which doesn't require you to keep amending a regex?

Comment: @deceze Yes! This is exactly what I hope to get to but I'm not familiar enough with how to figure out how to change the regex value in order to detect new emojis. I know how to get the emoji value just don't know how to modify the code Iv'e provided so it'll detect this new emoji. I know it will need to be updated frequently, just how to start with this.