# Accented letters and emojis

Tags: swift, swift3, emoji

I need to encode/decode emojis, I'm using this code

```
var encodeEmoji: String{
        if let encodeStr = NSString(cString: self.cString(using: .nonLossyASCII)!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue){
            return encodeStr as String
        }
        return self
    }
```

For emojis all is fine, but when I'm coding Accented letters (*æ, ø, å*) I have something like this **\346, \370, \345**
Could anyone help to avoid converting of Accented letters, or say, what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to encode each character separately, detecting Emojis:

```
let testString = "abcdřšá"

let encoded = testString.unicodeScalars
    .map {
        guard $0.isEmoji else { return String($0) }
        let data = String($0).data(using: .nonLossyASCII, allowLossyConversion: true)!
        return String(data: data, encoding: .ascii)!
    }.joined()

print(encoded) // abcdřšá\ud83d\ude03\ud83d\ude03\ud83d\ude03
```

Using the `isEmoji` method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39425959/669586).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Great solution