# How to display different emoji sizes in a TextView/TextField?

Tags: ios, swift, emoji

Does anybody know how can I accomplish the effect of different emoji sizes like in messaging apps? If there is only one emoji sent in a message then its bigger, if there are two they are smaller, if they are sent inline with the text then its "normal" (text) size etc.

Oh, and it would be great if the answer is in Swift :)

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757193/find-out-if-character-in-string-is-emoji) will help you find if the string contains only one emoji or otherwise.

Comment: To display them larger properly use AppleColorEmoji font