# How to get the some part from string which has emoj using nsrange

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsrange

I have text which has emoji in it,I have to get the substring using Nsrange.

I am not getting the substring because of emoji, I am using the below code to find the substring and it is working fine when emoji is not present. Thnaks for the quick answers.

```
    extension String {
    //for finding the range
    func nsRanges(ofWord word: String) -> [NSRange] {
        var ranges: [NSRange] = []
        self.enumerateSubstrings(in: startIndex..., options: .byWords) {
            (substring, range, _, _) in

            let subrange = NSRange(range, in: self)

            let othersubstring = self.substring(location: subrange.location, length: word.count + 1)
           if othersubstring != nil{
                if othersubstring!  == word + " " {
                    ranges.append(NSRange(location: subrange.location, length: word.count))

                }
            }
        }
        return ranges
    }
    //for substring *emphasized text*
    func substring(location: Int, length: Int) -> String? {
        guard self.utf16.count >= location + length else {

            return nil
        }
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: location)
        let end = index(startIndex, offsetBy: location + length)
        return substring(with: start..<end)
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to refer to this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757193/find-out-if-character-in-string-is-emoji

Comment: @Bappaditya hw it is solve my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `NSRange` to get substrings in Swift at all.

There are two convenience API's to convert `NSRange` to `Range<String.Index>` and vice versa

- `init?(_ range: NSRange, in string: String)` in`Range`
- `NSRange(_ range: Range<String.Index>, in string: StringProtocol)` in `NSRange`

For example replace the second function with

```
extension String {

    func substring(location: Int, length: Int) -> String? {
        let nsRange = NSRange(location: location, length: length)
        guard let range = Range(nsRange, in: self) else { return nil }
        return String(self[range])
    }
}
```