# Swift – How to remove special character without remove emoji from string?

Tags: swift, string, special-characters, emoji

How can all special characters be removed from a string without also removing emojis?

I've tried:

```
func removeSpecialCharsFromString(text: String) -> String {
    let okayChars : Set<Character> = 
        Set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-& ".characters)
    return String(text.characters.filter {okayChars.contains($0) })
}
```

– but this function also removes the emoji from the string.

**Expected Result:**

> "Hello guys !? Need some money $ "

**Actual Result:**

> "Hello guys Need some money "

Comment: This could be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757193/find-out-if-character-in-string-is-emoji

Comment: @mag_zbc Thanks, but I don't see how that link can help me.I already use the extension to see if my string contains emoji or not.

Comment: What do you mean by a "special character"? Do you mean "any non ASCII except emojis" or "English punctuation" or something else? Would the letter ü be considered a special character?

Comment: i mean all non ASCII character except emojis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below extension to make your sentence perfect as per desired output.

```
extension String {
    var condensedWhitespace: String {
        let components = self.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        return components.filter { !$0.isEmpty }.joined(separator: " ")
    }

    func removeSpecialCharacters() -> String {
        let okayChars = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 ")
        return String(self.unicodeScalars.filter { okayChars.contains($0) || $0.properties.isEmoji })
    }
}
```

Example.

```
let input = "Hello guys !? Need some money $ "

print(input.removeSpecialCharacters().condensedWhitespace)
// Hello guys Need some money
```

Comment: Awesome guys, it works like a charm ! Thanks you so much !

Answer (score 2):

The question here is how to understand if a character is an emoji or not. Swift has a handy [`isEmoji`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode/scalar/properties/3081577-isemoji) method that we can use.

Here is the updated function with the usage of `isEmoji` method:

```swift
func removeSpecialCharacters(from text: String) -> String {
    let okayChars = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890-& ")
    return String(text.unicodeScalars.filter { okayChars.contains($0) || $0.properties.isEmoji })
}
```

And just in case someone is going to test the code above in Playground:

```swift
let input = "Hello guys !? Need some money $ "
let output = removeSpecialCharacters(from: input)
print(output)                    // Prints: Hello guys  Need some money
```