# Intercept all emojs inside a string

Tags: c#, regex, emoticons

I have to intercept all emojs inside a string

```
input   "bla bla   bla  "
desired output  "bla bla <b></b>  bla  <b></b>"
```

my code is

```
string input = "bla bla   bla  ";
var output1 = Regex.Replace(input, @"[\p{C}]|[\p{So}]|[\u20E3]+", "<b>$1</b>");
var output2 = Regex.Replace(input, @"[\p{C}]|[\p{So}]|[\u20E3]+", "emj");


output 1:
bla bla <b>$1</b><b>$1</b>  bla  <b>$1</b><b>$1</b>

output2
bla bla emjemj  bla  emjemj
```

Comment: I would check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757193/find-out-if-character-in-string-is-emoji

Comment: You might want to be more explicit on what you are trying to achieve.  My first read of you "question" (note, there is no question mark in your question) was to say to myself "Uh, so..."

Comment: I would like to insert an html tag around every emoji found 
desired output  "bla bla <b></b>  bla  <b></b>"

Comment: I don't think the *answered question* answers your question (from my understanding - that's why you need to be explicit).  I got things working by using the non-static version of `Regex.Replace` and by changing your pattern somewhat: `const string emojiPattern = @"(\p{C}|\p{So}|\u20E3)+"; var regex = new Regex(emojiPattern); var replaced = regex.Replace(input, "<b>$1</b>");`

Comment: Edit your question to ask want you really want. The duped question answers what you "ask" in the title. Change the title, be explicit (and ask a real question) in the body. If the question gets reopened,  send a comment to me and I'll expand on my comment above with a real answer. Otherwise, my comment above *should* help you out.