# Access unicodeScalars from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39425959/2512312) about detecting emojis in Swift 5 using `unicodeScalars` I'm wondering how I can access this in a Objective-C project. I know that Swift-Libs can be accessed in Objective-C, but is there an easier way to access just `unicodeScalars` and doing something similar to the linked answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following the answer it can be changed a little bit to make it work with Bridging back to ObjC..

```
@objc extension NSString {

    var containsEmoji : Bool {
        let uni = self as String
        for scalar in uni.unicodeScalars {
            switch scalar.value {
            case 0x1F600...0x1F64F, // Emoticons
                 0x1F300...0x1F5FF, // Misc Symbols and Pictographs
                 0x1F680...0x1F6FF, // Transport and Map
                 0x2600...0x26FF,   // Misc symbols
                 0x2700...0x27BF,   // Dingbats
                 0xFE00...0xFE0F,   // Variation Selectors
                 0x1F900...0x1F9FF, // Supplemental Symbols and Pictographs
                 0x1F1E6...0x1F1FF: // Flags
                return true
            default:
                continue
            }
        }
        return false
    }

}
```

let's test..

```
NSString *normal = @"hello world";
NSString *special = @" badewelt";
if ([special containsEmoji]) {
    NSLog(@"emoji inside %@",special);
} else {
    NSLog(@"no emoji inside %@",special);
}
// or with dot syntax
if (normal.containsEmoji) {
    NSLog(@"emoji inside %@",normal);
} else {
    NSLog(@"no emoji inside %@",normal);
}
```

output

```
emoji inside  badewelt
no emoji inside hello world
```

Comment: In my case I needed to do `public var`, other than that, your answer helped me a lot